# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties 'DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI.HtmlHelperExtension.DevExpress<Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel

Tags: model-view-controller, devexpress, umbraco

While my devexpress version is 14.1 my project was working perfectly on local host but after I upload to server my devexpress started recieve the following error =>

The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI.HtmlHelperExtension.DevExpress(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper)' and 'DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI.HtmlHelperExtension.DevExpress(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper)'

@Html.DevExpress().GetStyleSheets( 
new DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI.StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.NavigationAndLayout }, 
new DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI.StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Editors },

Comment: This seems to describe the same problem. https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q579169

Comment: possible duplicate of [The call is ambiguous beetween the following methods or properties MVC, devexpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885984/the-call-is-ambiguous-beetween-the-following-methods-or-properties-mvc-devexpre)